# $A,B,C,D$ on a circle. $\widehat{BAC}=\widehat{BDC}$

Tags: geometry

Points $A,B,C,D$ belong to a circle. What's a rigorous yet simple proof that $\widehat{BAC}=\widehat{BDC}$ ?

Does this property have a name?

[image: ![A,B,C,D belong to a circle, BAC=BDC]

---

I get that in the above figure:

- summing angles, $\widehat{BOA}+\widehat{AOC}=\widehat{BOC}=\widehat{BOD}+\widehat{DOC}$
- sum of the angles of isosceles triangle $AOB$ is $\Pi$, thus
  $\widehat{BOA}=\Pi-2\widehat{BAO}\quad$ and similarly
  $\widehat{AOC}=\Pi-2\widehat{OAC}\quad$
  $\widehat{BOD}=\Pi-2\widehat{BDO}\quad$
  $\widehat{DOC}=\Pi-2\widehat{ODC}\quad$
- replacing then simplifying, we get
  $\widehat{BAO}+\widehat{OAC}=\widehat{BDO}+\widehat{ODC}\quad$ thus
  $\widehat{BAC}=\widehat{BDC}\quad$ <sub><sup>Q.E.D.</sup></sub>

However this reasoning seems dependent on the order of points on the circle, and perhaps other hypothesis.

Comment: Inscribed angles are half the central ones?

Comment: Vsauce's Michael (on the channel DONG) made [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJwRsoxe3VE) about Thale's theorem recently. It's the special case where $BC$ is a diagonal. However, the ideas of the proof are applicable in general. You could take a look.

Comment: Also this is informally called bow-tie theorem.

Comment: @abc... Nice pick. I (now) see that's also the [Opera House theorem](http://www.jamestanton.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Curriculum-Essay_April-2014_CIRCLE-THEOREMS.pdf#page=4).

Comment: @fgrieu: It's most-commonly known as (a corollary to) the [Inscribed Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle). ("Opera House Theorem" may be local to Australia (and/or the author of that note), due to the figure's resemblance to the [Sydney Opera House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sydney_Opera_House).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here is a proof that an angle inscribed in an arc is half the intersepted arc.
That is, $m\angle APB=\frac{1}{2}m(arc \widehat{ACB})$

Following the figure, let $\mathrm{M}$ be the center of the circle, and 
$\angle APB=\alpha , \angle APM=\beta\\
\mathrm{Now, \: in \: \Delta MPB,}\\
\mathrm{MP}=\mathrm{MB}\\
\implies \angle MPB= \angle MBP= \alpha + \beta\\
\implies \angle CMB= 2 ( \alpha +\beta)\\
\: \\
\mathrm{In \: \Delta MPA,}\\
\mathrm{MP} =\mathrm{MA} \\
\angle MPA= \angle MAP= \beta \\
\implies \angle CMA=2\beta\\
\mathrm{Since \:} \angle CMB= \angle CMA+ \angle AMB\\
2(\alpha+ \beta)= 2\beta + \angle AMB\\
\implies 2\alpha=\angle AMB\\
\: \\
\mathrm{And, \: since\:} \angle APB=\alpha, \mathrm{we \: have \: shown \:that} \\
\boxed{\angle APB=\frac{1}{2} \angle AMB} $

Now, your statement, that is, angles inscribed in the same arc are congruent, is a direct consequence of the previous theorem.

For in your case, 
$\angle BAC= \frac{1}{2}\angle BOC\\
\angle BDC=\frac{1}{2}\angle BOC\\ 
\implies \angle BAC=\angle BDC$

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known property of angles, inscribed in a chord of a circle: they are congruent if they are inscribed on the same side of the chord (BC in your case) and supplementary if inscribed on opposite sides of the chord.

Comment: Yes I (now) see that what I ask is a most direct application of that [fact/theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle), which vaguely rings a bell. Yet that theorem is not in the curriculum of my daughter (11th grade) and we are seeking a rigorous simple proof of an exercise she's given, if there is one.